# How could ArrayDeque has unlimited size with an array backup

Tags: java, arraydeque

I read this *"Array deques have no capacity restrictions"* from here:

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#:~:text=Array%20deques%20have%20no%20capacity,Null%20elements%20are%20prohibited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#:%7E:text=Array%20deques%20have%20no%20capacity,Null%20elements%20are%20prohibited).

However, in the source code I found it's using an array (maximum capacity is Integer.MAX_VALUE), and it will throw exception when growing up:

```java
if ((minCapacity = oldCapacity + needed) - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0) {
    if (minCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Sorry, deque too big");
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

I'm confused, does ArrayDeque really have unlimited size?

Comment: It has a _theoretically_ unlimited size but the practical limit is the limit of arrays which can only have up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements. For most applications that's enough though - are you running into any problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas already mentioned in his comment, the practical limit is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which equals to `2,147,483,647` ~ `68 GB`. Thus, the javadoc of ArrayDeque is only correct regarding the theory behind it, but not the actual implementation.

I cannot think of a scenario, which would justify to use ArrayDeque to its maximum capacity. IMHO it would only be the symptom of a very bad code design and should be avoided.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, given the fact a byte array of 2^31 length can take 2^39 bit which is ~68 GB, not too much host can handle that. - And it's a very bad use case.